# What is the right way to update android manifest with xbuild and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest, xmlpoke

In our environment we are building xamarin.android project and would like to pass $(build_number) variable to Jenkins build. Unfortunately Jenkins is building the project as if nothing was passed to the build workflow.

I tried to use XmlPoke which works fine for windows and doesn't work on mac at all.

os: mac os x
jenkins & xamarin are the latest stable version

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you asking how to configured a Jenkins parameterized build, or are you asking how to use your android build command line with parameters? As a matter of fact: what IS your android build command line?

Comment: this one "or are you asking how to use your android build command line with parameters". I'm using XBUILD (mac os x)

Comment: So, Jenkins aside, how do you usually pass variables to Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default solution/plugin for it if you are building under Mac OS Host.
You have to create your own script/tool with input parameters to update xml attributes to a given value.
Then use it with shell exec task.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good solution from http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/xamarin-android-builds-in-jenkins

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" '$(JENKINS)' == '1' ">
<XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionCode" Value="$(SVN_REVISION)" />
<XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionName" Value="2.0.$(SVN_REVISION)" />
</Target>
```

Use it in your .csproj file and don't forget to set 'JENKINS' as a global environment with a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**this link**](http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/xamarin.android-builds-in-jenkins), you can access environment build variables in csproj file using `$(VAR)` notation.

So, predefined Jenkins variables, such as `BUILD_NUMBER` should be available directly inside your project use `$(BUILD_NUMBER)`, nothing extra required during invocation.

Comment: what does it mean to "use inside you project". Yes, I have that variable but I need to update the manifest/plist with the build number. Basically modify an xml file during build process

Comment: Your question states: "we are building xamarin.android project and would like **to pass $(build_number) variable to Jenkins build**". I further asked you in comments what you wanted, and you confirmed "how to use your **android build command line with parameters**". I've answered how to pass/use variables to your android build. Nowhere did you ask about updating xml

Comment: I didn't understood the comment. The question is in subject "What is the right way to update android manifest with xbuild and Jenkins"